# Python installation and setting error

Tags: python

I follow official document that directs installation and setting of Python 3.5 in Windows7. However, i couldn't initiate my python study and was blocked by either NameError or SyntaxError, they look like:
[image]

Working environment is Window7 64bit. And here is how i set my python path:
[image]

[image]

Are there anything wrong with my setting commands? Or am i using the incorrect version? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to run a python file from python shell.

Either run the file like > Python myscript.py OR type commands in python shell like >>> print ("Hello World").

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much. Learning Data structure and Algorithm theory with starter level python. Long way to go.